# My angular form validation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap with angular, and I disabled bootstrap's validation, angular still doesn't work. It seems that I already set everything.

My code likes below, every input's validation didn't.

```
<form novalidate name="new_people" ng-if="is_editting_newpeople" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="save_new_people()">    
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">True Name</div>
        <input class="form-control" name="realname" type="text" ng-model="editting_people.realname" autofocus required>
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">Nickname</div>
        <input type="text" name="nickname" class="form-control" id="nickname" ng-model="editting_people.nickname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">Mobilenumber</div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobilenumber" ng-model="editting_people.mobilenumber" required ng-minlength=11>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default
                        dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ editting_people.idclass.name }}
                      <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li ng-repeat="id_class in IDCLASSES">
                    <a ng-click="set_id_class(id_class)">{{ id_class.name }}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /btn-group -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="editting_people.idnumber" required name="idnumber">
    </div>
    <!-- /input-group -->
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input class="btn btn-default" value="取消" type="button" ng-click="cancel_new_people()" />
</form>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? I am not able to see any time of validations you put for the elements in the post.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by input doesn't work? 
Post your code of related controller please, because it is not clear what validation are you doing. If you have `novalidate` you should organize validation in your angular controller or HTML, e.g.:

```
<div ng-show="editting_people.realname.length<4">
 Any error message here.
</div>
```